# Why filezilla can't call program to open mp4 file?

Tags: linux, filezilla

OS info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-2 (2023-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lxde version info:

```
sudo dpkg -l  lxde
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  lxde           11           all          metapackage for LXDE
```

I have already bind smplayer with mp4 file.

[image]

The smplayer will open mp4 file when to double click mp4 file,maybe it means that program is associated with mp4 file.

Open mp4 file with filezilla:

[image]

[image]

[image]